# Using Selinium, Scrapy, Python to retrieve public facebook wall post of user profile

Tags: javascript, python, facebook, selenium, scrapy

I'm trying to retrieve my wallpost of a public profile. I need to check that a message is arriving to my wall and is being delivered within a given timestamp. I am essentially writing a monitoring check to validate message delivery of our messaging system. I'm getting a No Connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. Not quite sure why?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Many times when crawling we run into problems where content that is rendered on the page is generated with Javascript and therefore scrapy is unable to crawl for it (eg. ajax requests, jQuery craziness). However, if you use Scrapy along with the web testing framework Selenium then we are able to crawl anything displayed in a normal web browser.
#
# Some things to note:
# You must have the Python version of Selenium RC installed for this to work, and you must have set up Selenium properly. Also this is just a template crawler. You could get much crazier and more advanced with things but I just wanted to show the basic idea. As the code stands now you will be doing two requests for any given url. One request is made by Scrapy and the other is made by Selenium. I am sure there are ways around this so that you could possibly just make Selenium do the one and only request but I did not bother to implement that and by doing two requests you get to crawl the page with Scrapy too.
#
# This is quite powerful because now you have the entire rendered DOM available for you to crawl and you can still use all the nice crawling features in Scrapy. This will make for slower crawling of course but depending on how much you need the rendered DOM it might be worth the wait.


    from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
    from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
    from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
    from scrapy.http import Request
    import time
    from selenium import selenium

    class SeleniumSpider(CrawlSpider):
        name = "SeleniumSpider"
        start_urls = ["https://www.facebook.com/chronotrackmsgcheck"]

        rules = (
            Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('\.html', )), callback='parse_page',follow=True),
        )

        def __init__(self):
            CrawlSpider.__init__(self)
            self.verificationErrors = []
            self.selenium = selenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome", "https://www.facebook.com/chronotrackmsgcheck")
            self.selenium.start()

        def __del__(self):
            self.selenium.stop()
            print self.verificationErrors
            CrawlSpider.__del__(self)

        def parse_page(self, response):
            item = Item()

            hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
            #Do some XPath selection with Scrapy
            hxs.select('//div').extract()

            sel = self.selenium
            sel.open(response.url)

            #Wait for javscript to load in Selenium
            time.sleep(2.5)

            #Do some crawling of javascript created content with Selenium
            sel.get_text("//div")
            yield item

    SeleniumSpider()
```

Comment: Scraping Facebook is not allowed by them if you don't have written permission from them. I would suggest reading https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php

Comment: @WizKid - "Crawling" Facebook is legit. Google and other search engines crawl public profiles every day.

Comment: @Grant-Zukel If you set your useragent to something that looks like a common webcrawler, you won't need to run or wait for any JS. In fact, you might be able to omit Selenium completely in that case and simply fetch the HTML and parse it. I don't know what the right user-agent might be, but start with what Google bot uses. WRT the error, I can't help.

Comment: @sstur did you read the link I posted? I bet Google have written permission from Facebook to do it. And according to https://www.facebook.com/robots.txt Google bot and a few other bots are allowed to scrape Facebook. But it ends with: User-agent: *, Disallow: / . Which means for anyone else it is not allowed

Comment: sstur you are wrong, I'll post working code shortly.

Comment: @WizKid - Facebook forces users to scrape their site by providing an API that prevents users from accessing their own data, in order to increase Facebook's profits. If they don't want me to scrape their site, then they could make an API that lets me easily get the data I want ... until then, I'm ignoring robots.txt and scraping whatever I want, and I would encourage anyone else to do the same (with the disclaimer that you have to be careful, because if they catch you, they will ban you and possibly sue you, depending on what you do with the data).

Answer (score 4):

Here is the answer. This will parse the users profile using selenium and then parse only what is considered text on the page. You will have to do your own algorithm for data mining if you want to use it, but it works for my purposes.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/profileusername")
inputEmail = driver.find_element_by_id("email")
inputEmail.send_keys("facebookemail")
inputPass = driver.find_element_by_id("pass")
inputPass.send_keys("facebookpassword")
inputPass.submit()
page_text = (driver.page_source).encode('utf-8')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_text)

parse_data = soup.get_text().encode('utf-8').split('Grant Zukel') #if you use your name extactly how it is displayed on facebook it will parse all post it sees, because your name is always in every post.

latest_message = parse_data[3]
driver.close()
print latest_message
```

This is how I'm getting the latest post by the user:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/fbusername")
inputEmail = driver.find_element_by_id("email")
inputEmail.send_keys("fbemail")
inputPass = driver.find_element_by_id("pass")
inputPass.send_keys("fbpass")
inputPass.submit()
page_text = (driver.page_source).encode('utf-8')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_text)
parse_data = soup.get_text().encode('utf-8').split('Grant Zukel')    
latest_message = parse_data[4]
latest_message = parse_data[4].split('·')
driver.close()
time = latest_message[0]
message = latest_message[1]
print time,message
```